# Retrieve Data to Excel file from other software

Tags: excel, winapi, vba

I got a question on the Excel VBA with other software running in my PC.

I created a excel file and used DDE to connect the data from the trading software (SPTrader) is fine.

Now I want to retrieve the traded record back to the excel file for other purpose.

Then I used WinAPI FindWindow and FindWindowEX to find the window of traded record field under the account section in the SPTrader. I also can use ShowWindow (SW_MAXIMIZE/ SW_RESTORE) to test the window and proofed I was get a correct area.

On these area, the software is only allow to use mouse right-click then select the “Copy all Trade” from drop down list. Not allow Ctrl+C.

But when I use the SendMessage (CB_GETLBTEXT, CB_SELECTSTRING, LB_GETTEXT, LB_GETITEMDATA, LB_GETTEXTLEN) and pointed to the window (by hwnd) for getting records but it return 0.

Now I just use the VBA code to set the whole software to a specify position and sizing for window. Then call the mouse cursor to the location and do the right-click and select the “Copy all Trade”, and paste into the excel file.

So, my question is:
Is it possible to retrieve data from the trade record area by VBA?
What is the type of this area? Table, Listbox, Recordset…?
How to retrieve data when a trade is done without manually run the function?

Thank you very much!

```
Public Sub TradesOrder()
    Dim mainwnd As String
    Dim mainwnd_ac As String
    Dim hwnd As String
    Dim Chwnd1 As String
    Dim Chwnd2 As String
    Dim Chwnd3 As String
    Dim Chwnd4 As String
    Dim Chwnd5 As String
    Dim Chwnd6 As String
    Dim Chwnd7 As String

    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wb As String
    Dim sht As String
    Dim dirty As Long

    wb = "SPTrader_Excel_KK.xlsm"

    sht = "SPTrader_XLS"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wkb = Workbooks("SPTrader_Excel_KK.xlsm")

    If wkb Is Nothing Then
        Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wb)
        Workbooks(wb).Activate
        Worksheets(sht).Activate
    Else
        Workbooks(wb).Activate
        Worksheets(sht).Activate
    On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    mainwnd = Worksheets(sht).Range("AC1").Value
    mainwnd_ac = Worksheets(sht).Range("AC2").Value

    hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, mainwnd)
    Chwnd1 = FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0&, "MDIClient", vbNullString)
    Chwnd2 = FindWindowEx(Chwnd1, 0&, "TfrmAccBox", vbNullString)
    Chwnd3 = FindWindowEx(Chwnd2, 0&, "TPageControl", vbNullString)
    Chwnd4 = FindWindowEx(Chwnd3, 0&, "TTabSheet", "Order")
    Chwnd5 = FindWindowEx(Chwnd4, 0&, "TAdvStringGrid", vbNullString)
    Chwnd6 = FindWindowEx(Chwnd5, 0&, "TAdvRichEdit", vbNullString) 'TAdvRichEdit 'TGridDatePicker

    SetWindowPos hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 850, 620, SWP_SHOWWINDOW
    BringWindowToTop Chwnd2
    BringWindowToTop Chwnd4
    ShowWindow Chwnd4, SW_NORMAL
    SetCursorPos 500, 540                           'x and y mouse position
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0   'RightClick
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0     'RightClick
    Sleep 100
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0   'RightClick
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0     'RightClick
    SendKeys "{DOWN}"
    SendKeys "{DOWN}"
    Sleep 100
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"

    Worksheets(sht).Activate
    Worksheets(sht).Range("C25").Select
    Range("C25").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the window class of the "Trade Record"? Have you tried with Spy++?

Comment: Hi! EyIM,
Thank you for your interesting!
From the Spy++ under class page, the Class Name is window TAdvRichEdit, the Class Styles is 00000008 & CS_DBCLKS, the Class Bytes is 0.

Comment: This looks like a custom control. Chances that you can read a single cell from a compound grid control are virtually zero, unless that control implements automation interfaces. Sending random messages across process boundaries isn't going to get you very far. This is clearly not a listbox or combobox, so don't expect listbox- and combobox-specific messages to do any good.

Comment: Thanks, IInspectable! My question seem to be quite difficult. I tried to search around for the topic "retrieve data from custom control windows forms" in the internet. So, I saw the DataGridView may be nearly my situation, but I seem to only for VB.net~~ However I also found the video is exactly what I want. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxzfLpbvWEA&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I am not fixed this question yet, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Excel VBA, you can use EnumChildWindows function to find SP window handler  firstly from window title of "SPSytem'  ,and secondly also find its child window handler for today Trade record from title of "Account Info" ,title of "Order" and   Classname of "TAdvStringGrid".(Because the record area text is not in the title Edit text)After that, use SetForegroundWindow() and SetCursorPos() to locate the area of copy button under the today trade record. Using mouse_event to righ-click the copy button to save your record into system clipboard. Now you can paste it back to any  activated Excel worksheet with VBA code. The following attached  code for your reference only . You can test it on VBA module after opening new xls sheet. Finally the record result is pasted  at Range("A10:Z100")

Replace your SP trader Title with your version at VBA code:  str = "SPSystem R8.75.3".  Yours is R8.74.2.  Other classname and name should be same.

Be Reminded: the trade record area should be always shown and seen on window during VBA running , and don't hide it. For safe, ShowWindow() is used in the code. The VBA code is as followed.

```
   
    Private Declare Function SendMessageSTRING Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
    Public Declare Function SendDlgItemMessageW Lib "user32" (ByVal hdlg As Long, ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long, ByVal Msg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Private Const WM_GETTEXT = &HD
    Public Const CWP_ALL = 0
    Public Const CWP_SKIPINVISIBLE = 1
    Public Const CWP_SKIPDISABLED = 2
    Public Const CWP_SKIPTRANSPARENT = 3
    Public Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndParent _
        As Long, ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" _
       Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
      (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
       ByVal lpString As String, _
       ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" _
       Alias "GetClassNameA" _
      (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
       ByVal lpClassName As String, _
       ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
    Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, lpRect As RECT) As Long
    Private Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
    End Type
    Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
    Private Const BM_CLICK = &HF5
    Private Const BM_SETSTATE = &HF3
    Private Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN = &H201
    Private Const WM_LBUTTONUP = &H202
    Private Const MK_LBUTTON = &H1
    Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10
    Public Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal lHwnd As Long, _
        ByVal lCmdShow As Long) As Boolean
    Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As RECT) As Long
    Dim cReturn As Long, lParam As Long, parHwnd As Long
    Dim str As String, fhwnd As Long
    Sub traderecord()
    Range("A10:Z100").ClearContents
    str = "SPSystem R8.75.3"
    cReturn = EnumChildWindows(0, AddressOf EnumChildProc, lParam)
    Debug.Print str
    Debug.Print fhwnd
    str = "Account Info"
    cReturn = EnumChildWindows(fhwnd, AddressOf EnumChildProc, lParam)
    Debug.Print str
    Debug.Print Hex(fhwnd)
    fhwnd2 = fhwnd
    ShowWindow fhwnd2, 3
    str = "Order"
    cReturn = EnumChildWindows(fhwnd, AddressOf EnumChildProc, lParam)
    Debug.Print str
    Debug.Print fhwnd
    Range("A9") = "HWND"
    Range("B9") = Hex(fhwnd)
    str = "TAdvStringGrid"
    cReturn = EnumChildWindows(fhwnd, AddressOf EnumChildProc, lParam)
    Debug.Print str
    Debug.Print Hex(fhwnd)
    Range("A9") = "HWND"
    Range("B9") = Hex(fhwnd)
    ForegroundHwnd2 = SetForegroundWindow(fhwnd)
    Dim rt As RECT
    GetCursorPos rt
    x = rt.Left
    y = rt.Top
    Debug.Print x & "=="
    GetWindowRect fhwnd, rt
    Debug.Print rt.Top
    SetCursorPos rt.Left + 10, rt.Top + 30
    Sleep 200
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
    SetCursorPos rt.Left + 30, rt.Top + 60
    Sleep 200
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Sleep 500
    ShowWindow fhwnd2, 1
    'Range("A1").Copy
    'Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
    'Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
    'DataObj.GetFromClipboard
    ' strPaste = DataObj.GetText(1)
    'Debug.Print strPaste
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Activate
    ws.Range("A10").Select
    ws.Paste
    SetCursorPos x, y
    str = "Microsoft Excel"
    cReturn = EnumChildWindows(0, AddressOf EnumChildProc, lParam)
    Debug.Print str
    Debug.Print Hex(fhwnd)
    ForegroundHwnd2 = SetForegroundWindow(fhwnd)
    ws.Range("A10").Select
    End Sub
    Private Function EnumChildProc(ByVal lHwnd As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
        Dim RetVal As Long
        Dim WinClassBuf As String * 255, WinTitleBuf As String * 255
        Dim WinClass As String, WinTitle As String
        Dim ChildCount As Integer    ' Number of Child Windows
        Dim cLV As Long                 ' Child window handle
        RetVal = GetClassName(lHwnd, WinClassBuf, 255)
        WinClass = StripNulls(WinClassBuf)  ' remove extra Nulls & spaces
        RetVal = GetWindowText(lHwnd, WinTitleBuf, 255)
        WinTitle = StripNulls(WinTitleBuf)
        ChildCount = ChildCount + 1
        If WinClass = "ListView20WndClass" Then    ' ListView Window
           cLV = lHwnd
            EnumChildProc = False
        Else
            EnumChildProc = True
        End If
        If (InStr(WinClass, str) > 0 Or InStr(WinTitle, str) > 0) Then
        Debug.Print ChildCount & " Child Handle: " & Hex(lHwnd); lHwnd; "   Child Class = "; WinClass; ", Title = "; WinTitle
        fhwnd = lHwnd
        EnumChildProc = False
        End If
        End Function
        Private Function StripNulls(OriginalStr As String) As String
        If (InStr(OriginalStr, Chr(0)) > 0) Then
          OriginalStr = Left(OriginalStr, InStr(OriginalStr, Chr(0)) - 1)
        End If
        StripNulls = OriginalStr
        End Function
```